# $\sigma$-compact space of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Yesterday I solved for pseudo compact sets which are closed and bounded, and with the help of stack exchange I learnt that any subspace is Lindelöf.My problem is only $\sigma$-compact set that has not been solved.

My question is what kind of subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ would be $\sigma$-compact.

I have solve that $\sigma$-compactness is not equivalent to bounded and closed, how could it would be?

Some clues will be grateful.Thanks!

Comment: A subset of $\mathbb R^{n}$ is $\sigma-$ compact if and only if it is an $F_{\sigma}$. There is no simple description of all $F_{\sigma}$ sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a $\sigma$-compact subspace $A\subset(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}^n})$ is a countable union of compact sets.
Since a compact set in $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}^n})$ is closed, $A$ is an $F_{\sigma}$.
Conversely, suppose $A$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ set in $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}^n})$, namely, $A$ is a countable union of closed sets.
To verify that $A$ is $\sigma$-compact it suffices to show that all the closed sets in $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}^n})$ are $\sigma$-compact, because the countable union of countable sets is still countable.
Assume that $B$ is an arbitrary closed set in $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}^n})$.
Define $Q_k$ to be the closed square $[-k,k]^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Observe that for a fixed $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $Q_k$ is closed and bounded.
From Heine-Borel theorem, it follows that $Q_k$ is also compact.
Moreover, $Q_k\cap B$ is compact, because it is closed in a compact subspace $Q_k$.
In light of
$$B=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}Q_k\cap B,$$
we have that $B$ is $\sigma$-compact, which completes the proof.